# C# - Dictionary, Can i set type of value in constructor? .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, .net-2.0

Is there any way how to achieve something like this? I have found that dynamic can be solution but its from .NET 4.0+ :/

```
 public class Message
        {
            public int ID;
            Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> dict

            public Message(int ID, Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> Data)
            {
                this.ID = ID;
                dict = Data
            }
        }
```

The reason is because sometimes i want dictionary with string:string and sometimes with string:int so I would like to have this class a little dynamic and not 2 classes.

Comment: Can you make the class `Message` generic too or is this not an option?

Comment: So, `Dictionary<string, object>`? Usually when you think you need `dynamic`, you don't.

Comment: @CodeCaster The visual studio says you can not pass dictionary string:string into string:object

Comment: I dont want two dictionaries sometimes instance of Message should have int values and sometimes string values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dictionary can hold that one at one time and that one at another time, it should be actually two different dictionaries. This goes with the SOLID-principle, meaning that any class and even any member of a class serves *one single* purpose. Having an object doing the one in scenario 1 and something different in scenario 2 is usually a broken design and you should consider to create two different things.

Alternativly go with generics, this is `Dictionary<T, U>` where you have to pass `T` and `U` to your `Message`-class:

```
public class Message<T, U>
{
    public int ID;
    private readonly Dictionary<T, U> dict;

    public Message(int ID, Dictionary<T, U> Data)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        dict = Data;
    }
}
```

Now you can make instances like this:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var m = new Message<string, string>(0, myDict);
```

which will automatically infer the right types for `T` and `U` depending on your defintion of `myDict`.

Comment: It does not seem that it fill types automatically. I have got error that `Using  the generic type "Message<T,U> requires two type arguments` at line `var m = new Message(0, myDict)`

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "key1", "data1" },
                { "key2", "data2" }
            };`

Comment: Indeed, this doesn´t work for constructor. You have to provide the generic parameters also, as shown in my last edit.

Comment: Ahh perfect ! Thank you this is first time i have met something like this.

Comment: If you don´t want to pass the generic arguments everytime you create a new `Message` use a factory as shown by InBetween. In contrast to a constructor you *can* omit the type-arguments and let the compiler infer them from the provided paremeters.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a generic factory method, and this way you don't even have to burden the user with types:

```
public static class MessageFactory
{
    public static Message<TKey, TValue> Create<TKey, TValue>(int ID, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> data) 
        => new Message<TKey, TValue>(ID, data);

    public class Message<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public Message(int ID, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> data) { ... }
    }
}
```

And now usage is almost the same as your `dynamic` solution, but much safer:

```
var message = MessageFactory.Create(1, someDictionary);
```

Type inference will take care of working out the types of `TKey` and `TValue`.

P.S. Making `Message<,>` nested or not is entirely optional. I like it this way in order to unclutter as much as possible the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generics

```
 public class MyClass<T>
    {
         private readonly Dictionary<string, T> _data;

        public MyClass( Dictionary<string, T> newData)
        {
            _data = newData;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, T> Data
        {
            get { return _data;}
        }

    }
```